# Angular 8, IE11 error on startup Function.prototype.toString: 'this' is not a Function object

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

Since upgrading to Angular 8, production builds with the Angular CLI fail on startup in IE11.
The error logged in the console is: "Function.prototype.toString: 'this' is not a Function object" and points to polyfills-es5.js.

The section in question in polyfills-es5.js is:

```
var InternalStateModule = __webpack_require__(
  /*! ../internals/internal-state */
  "./node_modules/core-js/internals/internal-state.js");

var getInternalState = InternalStateModule.get;
var enforceInternalState = InternalStateModule.enforce;
var TEMPLATE = String(nativeFunctionToString).split('toString');
shared('inspectSource', function (it) {
  return nativeFunctionToString.call(it);
});
(module.exports = function (O, key, value, options) {
  var unsafe = options ? !!options.unsafe : false;
  var simple = options ? !!options.enumerable : false;
  var noTargetGet = options ? !!options.noTargetGet : false;

  if (typeof value == 'function') {
    if (typeof key == 'string' && !has(value, 'name')) hide(value, 'name', key);
    enforceInternalState(value).source = TEMPLATE.join(typeof key == 'string' ? key : '');
  }

  if (O === global) {
    if (simple) O[key] = value; else setGlobal(key, value);
    return;
  } else if (!unsafe) {
    delete O[key];
  } else if (!noTargetGet && O[key]) {
    simple = true;
  }

  if (simple) O[key] = value; else hide(O, key, value); // add fake Function#toString for correct work wrapped methods / constructors with methods like LoDash isNative
})(Function.prototype, 'toString', function toString() {
  return typeof this == 'function' && getInternalState(this).source || nativeFunctionToString.call(this);
});
```

I created a new app from scratch and that obviously works fine in IE11. So I tried to work backwards and remove packages/change config until it matched the default app but continued to get the error.

Comparing the generated polyfills-es5.js files for both, they are different, but I couldn't find any information about how exactly that file is generated (my polyfills.ts file is the same as the default app).

I'm out of ideas on how to further troubleshoot it.

Comment: I was getting this error with Angular 8.2.8, however after updating to Angular 8.2.10 it seems to be fixed. I can't see anything in the main Angular release notes that relates to this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue. I found out that with the differential loading actually you can remove everything but 'zone.js'.

However there is this bug: 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31678 which suggests a work-around (adding `.js` to the zone import).

Maybe it's related.

EDIT: Same as other answers, updating fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely looks related. Unfortunately I just went to test out the fix and it seems it's already fixed itself. Since posting this question, I've continued working on the app and there was an Angular patch release so I'm not sure what actually fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In tsconfig.json, target es5 (default is es6).
In polyfills.ts, uncomment IE polyfills.

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
   }
```

Polyfills.ts

```
     * BROWSER POLYFILLS
     */

    /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
    import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
    import 'core-js/es6/object';
    import 'core-js/es6/function';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
    import 'core-js/es6/number';
    import 'core-js/es6/math';
    import 'core-js/es6/string';
    import 'core-js/es6/date';
    import 'core-js/es6/array';
    import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
    import 'core-js/es6/map';
    import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
    import 'core-js/es6/set';

    /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
    import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

    /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
    import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


    /** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
    // Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
    import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

Comment: Those polyfills are no longer required as of Angular 8, they're included by default by the CLI, with the differential loading changes.

I should have mentioned I'm using the Angular CLI and I'm talking about a production build.

Comment: Did anybody find a solution on this issue? Still facing it in our project. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60298210/angular-site-is-not-working-in-microsoft-ie

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is related to the `@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs` package. Please check the polyfills.ts file, and verify whether it contains the following code:

```
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

Besides, you could also try to add this reference in the header of the index.html:

```
<!-- load webcomponents bundle, which includes all the necessary polyfills -->
<script src="node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js"></script>
```