# angular site is not working in Microsoft IE

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular 8 with dot net core 2.2. Everything is working fine, till I realized that application is working on chrome but not in internet explorer 11. I did some R&D and also go through the angular official website documentation https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

I also tried by changing target to "es5" in tsconfig.json but all these things, did not work.

The error I am getting in internet explorer

SCRIPT5002: Function.prototype.toString: 'this' is not a Function object polyfills-es5.js (4703,9)

Does anybody resolved this issue in past. It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: I stand corrected, seems they support all the way back to IE9, impressive, but I would still say that most new features would not work on old browsers, even with polyfill

Comment: Microsoft have officially stated that 1/12/2016 is the end of IE, and will no longer be supported, developing to that old browser is not only bad but could also be a security issue.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-ie-support

Comment: Yes I understand that, I have created a web site that is begin used by many users in same organisation. I can not force users to switch to chrome as they are comfortable with IE. That is why I am looking for solution on this.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Searching for a solution since days. I found an already closed issue exactly describing the obiuosly root cause of the problem: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31678#issuecomment-635132341. In IE 11 window is an Object, not a function. Cannot find any information about if the angular team is working on that.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/39672